# How to create Excel bar graph with ranges on x-axis while?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a dataset with a range of percentages. See image for a of subset of the data here.

> [image: Screenshot.]

I would like to create a bar graph which includes consistent ranges of percentages on the x-axis. Like this.

> [image: Screenshot.]

When I create a bar graph, I can only get it to look like this where the ranges are tiny and not consistent.

> [image: Screenshot.]

I have tried messing with the configurations on the format axis section but cannot seem to find where to control the range of each bar on the x-axis. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f818D.png)

Also, I would like to filter what data is on the chart based on a true/false column like you can see here. Include all 1's and filter out all 0's.

> [image: Screenshot.]

Requested screenshot of the “Format Axis” settings.

> [image: Requested Format Axis]

FWIW, I have created a bar graph using the data and tried looking through the graph configurations to see how to control the ranges on the x-axis. I cannot find where to control this. I tried googling it, but I don't know the correct terminology to use to describe this question and find an answer. I'm just asking for where to go to control these fields, not a free scripting request.

Comment: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: I have created a bar graph using the data and tried looking through the graph configurations to see how to control the ranges on the x-axis. I cannot find where to control this. I tried googling it, but I don't know the correct terminology to use to describe this question and find an answer.  I'm just asking for where to go to control these fields, not a free scripting request.

Comment: Format Axis -> Bounds and you can choose the minimum and maximum values for the axis

Comment: @NateHuff Everything you just posted in that comment should be a part of your question. As stated previously, the community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, that was my first assumption, but there are no options for Bounds under the Format Axis. I only see 'Bins' which does not allow me to control the overall range. Thanks

Comment: How about a screencap of what you see under Format Axis?

Comment: A screencap is in the original post. I have readded it to the bottom of the post. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you cannot select top/bottom bounds because I believe the horizontal axis is treated as non-numeric once you group values. Or perhaps it's because your horizontal is a category and therefore has limitations. Anyway, you can easily get around this by adding a 2nd filter column based on arbitrary top/bottom rules.

Create a pivot table with your data. Then you can (1) use a filter, and; (2) group by values such as 0.02 as I did below:

[image]

And if you need to further define a Top and Bottom (well, left and right in this case), add a 2nd filter column in your data and input your top/bottom formula.

Here's the worksheet with a 2nd filter added, a TRUE/FALSE where I defined my top and bottom rules (-.2 to .2).

[image]